# access an array in a different sub

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have a sub that creates an array and fills it with data, but I would like to use the same array (with the data recorded from previous sub) in a different sub/function. Is there a way to achieve that.

I'm quite new to VBA, so maybe I'm missing something obvious here.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

```
'//FIRST CODE
Dim MyResults() As String
'
'
'Fill MyResults() with data
'
'
Call ComboToText

'//SECOND CODE
Private Sub ComboToText()
'// If there is more than one item in MyResults() use combo box. For one item use Textbox.

Dim n As Long

If UBound(MyResults) > 1 Then
    txtPCB.Visible = False
    With cmbPCB
        .Visible = True
        For n = LBound(MyResults) To UBound(MyResults)
            .AddItem MyResults(n)
        Next n
        .Style = fmStyleDropDownCombo
    End With
Else
    txtPCB.Text = MyResults(1)
End With

End Sub
```

Whenever I'm trying to run, VBA insists on declaration of `MyResults()` in second code too. If I declare it again, wouldn't I lose the data that's already in it?

Comment: Move the declaration of the variable (e.g. `Dim xyz(10) As String`) to the start of the code module, before the start of your first `Sub` or `Function`, and the variable will have "module-level" scope and therefore be accessible to all `Sub`s and `Function`s in that code module.  If you paste some of the relevant code into your question, we can give you better guidance because in some cases it could be better to just pass the array as a parameter between the functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As YowE3K says, you can pass the array as an argument to another sub:

```
Dim MyResults() As String
'Fill MyResults() with data
Call ComboToText(MyResults)

'//SECOND CODE
Private Sub ComboToText(MyResults() As String)
...
```

It's fine to use the same name in both Subs, as I did, but you can also use a different name in the second Sub.